# Are there any visually accurate simulations of Higgs interactions?

Tags: simulations, higgs

For various fundamental phenomena, there are visually accurate simulations. For example: [electromagnetism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBU-kmOCIO4) or the [Schrödinger equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4wuSgwLT9I).

All I can find to visualize the Higgs Field is [this potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#/media/File:Mecanismo_de_Higgs_PH.png) in isolation.

Are there any accurate simulations out there which show the Higgs Field interacting with a system of particles -- how the Higgs Field itself changes in their presence, or how their own energies/wavefunctions/momenta are affected by the Higgs Mechanism (e.g. by artificially changing its strength)?

Comment: Except when we occasionally make a Higgs particle, the Higgs field doesn’t do anything interesting to simulate. It’s value is currently uniform and constant. Are you trying to understand what it did in the early universe?